# Notification with Alarm Manager doesn't work in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have searched and tried many source code for Notification.
Now i'm using this code to send Notification:

**AlarmMain**

```
    System.out.println("Lancio sveglia");

Date dat  = new Date();//initializes to now
    Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal_now.setTime(dat);
    cal_alarm.setTime(dat);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,18);//set the alarm time
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);



  //Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,
        34567, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);



    AlarmManager am =
        (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);

    am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

**AlarmReceiverActivity**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    System.out.println("Arrivo in AlarmReceiverActivity");

    Context context =  this.getApplicationContext();


    nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          CharSequence from = "[text]";
          CharSequence message = "S[text]";
          PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 001,
            new Intent(), 0);
          Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "[text]", System.currentTimeMillis());
          notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
          nm.notify(1, notif);
```

But the Notification alarm repeats in some devices every 30 minutes and in another every 1 hour.
But now I haven't setup an alarm repeat.

How I can setup the system to send the Notification once.
Any ideas?
Any help would be great